# How to achieve ALB weighted target groups with Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

There are new features on ALBs that allow for multiple target groups on a listener with a weighted priority. The potential configuration would allow for multiple action blocks on a aws_lb_listener_rule with a priority included.

AWS Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html

How can we achieve this with Terraform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, there's a delay when new features are announced by AWS and when they are available in Terraform since the Terraform resources need to implement the new API calls/functionality.

In this case, it looks like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10942) on the `terraform-provider-aws` repo to support this behavior. There's an open [pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/11606) that may fix the issue in **draft** mode.